# Getting started with Xcode, two n00b errors on the Signing & Capaiblities tab

Tags: xcode, xcode15

On the Signing & Capabilities tab, for iOS, there are 2 status alerts:

1. "Communication with Apple failed – Your team has no devices from which to generate a provisioning profile. Connect a device to use or manually add device IDs in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. [https://developer.apple.com/account/"](https://developer.apple.com/account/%22)
2. No profiles for 'ai.Questmode' were found Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'ai.Questmode'."

I confirmed that:

1. I'm using the latest version of Xcode (15.0.1)
2. My Apple Developer account is active
3. Restarting Xcode doesn't solve the problem (or smashing the "Try Again" button a million times)

Any suggestions how to fix these n00b errors? Thanks in advance.